# Display SVG's from an external file

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to display svg image from a local folder, but nothing happens.

My code is:

```
<svg class="logo">
       <use xlink:href="svg/logo.svg#logo_black"></use>    
</svg>
```

How can I fix it?
What am I missing?

Comment: What browser are you using? Firefox supports this.

Comment: More details please. Which browser(s) are you testing with?  Are you testing via a web server, or via the local filing system?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau
I'm using chrome, testing via my local filing system

Comment: Almost certainly a path problem but we can't diagnose what we have so far.

Comment: @Paulie_D I've attached the svg code: 

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 96">
 <title>logo</title>
 <g id="logo_black" data-name="logo">`

Comment: As I suggested this is probably a path issue. It looks like the SVG is in it's own folder which may be different from the HTML file.